# Kio estas la diferenco de la signifo inter “plejgrava” kaj “plej grava”?

Tags: adverbs, adjectives

Saluton, kio estas la diferenco de la signifo inter la du frazoj?

1. Li verkis sian plejgravan romanon.
2. Li verkis sian plej gravan romanon.

Antaŭdankon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La dua estas la ĝusta versio.

La vortoj *pli* kaj *plej* ludas la rolon de prefikso nur kiam oni bezonas unuopan vorton por unuopa koncepto. Ekzemple, ekzistas diferenco inter *pli bonigi* kaj *plibonigi*. Por transformi *plej amata homo* en unu vorton, oni skribas *plejamato*. Simile, *plej sankta ejo* fariĝas *plejsanktejo*.

En via ekzemplo, la vortoj *plej grava* ne bezonas ligon de tiu speco, do ili restas aparte. Kontraste, en *Dio, la Sinjoro, la Plejpotenca*, la vorto *plejpotenca* estas formulo kiu ne vere aludas tiumomentan komparon.

Comment: Dankon, Andrew, ja, vi vere estas la Plejpotenca (respondanto ĉikaze) en ĉi retejo. :-)